# What is the meaning of “bool operator()(TypeName *n) const” in C++

Tags: c++

For example

```
bool operator()(Point *p) const;
    {return f(p->pt);}
```

Is it possible that it returns a Boolean that if it is true call f?

Comment: overloading of "()" with return type bool

Comment: "it is possible that returns a Boolean that if is true calling f?" WAT?

Comment: What's with the extra `;` on the first line?

Answer (score 3):

This overloads the function-call operator for the type, for the case where one argument compatible with `Point*` is passed.  For example, if this was declared on type `Foo`:

```
Foo foo;
Point point;

// This calls the operator() method.
bool returnValue = foo(&point);
```

There is nothing magical about the body of this method; it will simply call function `f`, passing in `p->pt`, and return the result of that expression as a bool.  (What is actually happening within the method depends on the type of `f`.)

Answer (score 0):

it overloads the "function-call" operator, namely `operator()`, which allows you to use the object as a functor taking a parameter of type `TypeName*` (or which can be converted to it) and returning a bool.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a overload of function call operator which takes a Point object and returns a boolean value